# RelativeLayout - android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" AND android:gravity="center_horizontal" showing unexpected results

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to align some `TextViews` to the horizontal center within a `RelativeLayout`, but get some unexpected results when using certain properties:

1. Why does the second 'Spring Summer Autumn Winter' `TextView` and the first 'Hello World' `TextView` move to the horizontal center (even though they both use different horizontal text alignment properties)?
2. Using `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for the top `TextView` moves it to the center of the screen (which is not what I want)

Is there a property that can be used in order to align all `TextViews` to the horizontal centre?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Spring Summer Autumn Winter"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Spring Summer Autumn Winter"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView0"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layout_center_horizontal` - it's just for view position, not for the text inside. You can set gravity of text to control alignment inside `TextView`, but it won't work if you are using `RelativeLayout` with `wrap_content` views inside because in this case text is already centered well. Change it to `LinearLayout` with `match_parent`, for example - and use something like:

```
<TextView  
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/**yourtextstring**"
/>
```

Comment: Yes, it is. Just set text view height to wrap_content

Comment: The key is that will have text views one below another inside linear layout and views width would be stretched to parent, but text inside would be centered well. If you don't have background on your views - it's good solution.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for your help your suggestion worked best.

Answer (score 1):

> Replace this XML code with yours, I used `LinearLayout` instedof `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This Views show your all text as center of Screen, but if you want only as center horizontally then remove layout_gravity line of LinearLayout

Comment: Doesn't work. The 'Spring Summer Autumn Winter' textviews STILL don't align properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` works with `LinearLayout` while `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` works with `RelativeLayout`.
2. `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` adjust view in center of screen while it should be on center horizontal. For this use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`. It works for `RelativeLayout`.

For align all `TextView` center horizontal use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` property in parent `RelativeLayout`.
OR
`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` assign this to every `TextView`.

Below code will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView0"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Spring Summer Autumn Winter"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Spring Summer Autumn Winter"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```